# Remove header of column from table in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, header

after running the query:

```
SELECT title , year FROM movies WHERE title LIKE 'Harry Potter%' ORDER BY year;
```

[sql query output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb0gT.png

but i want to remove title and year headers from the table. How to do that?

Comment: please share sample data

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to turn the `header` off ?

```
SQLite version 3.32.2 2021-07-12 15:00:17
sqlite> insert into students(id, name) values (1, 'bob'), (2, 'jim'), (3, 'kim'), (4, 'paul');

sqlite> select * from students;
ID|NAME
1|bob
2|jim
3|kim
4|paul

sqlite> .header off
sqlite> select * from students;
1|bob
2|jim
3|kim
4|paul

sqlite> .header on
sqlite> select * from students;
ID|NAME
1|bob
2|jim
3|kim
4|paul
```

Comment: .header off is not working, i have tried that

Answer (score 0):

before executing your query just type ".mode quote" and you're good to go.
also to get the header back type ".mode table".
in [sqlite documention](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) you can find other arguments for .mode